# How to calculate Chi-Square density value only known P-value?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, distributions

Everywhere online there is how to calculate the Chi-Square density value given a confidence level: $\alpha$/p value; but I can not find how one calculates the inverse? How to calculate the $\alpha$/p-value knowing only the density value?

For example, if df = 4, and $\alpha$=0.95, then how does one calculate the $\chi^2_4$?

In R this would be `qchisq(0.95, 4)`= 9.4877. What is the math behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Given the degrees of freedom and an alpha value, `qchisq` essetnialy finds the point $x$ such that $F(x)=\alpha$, where $F$ is the CDF.

This is known as the $\alpha^{th}$ quantile.  The q in the `q*` functions stands for quantile, and so this class of R functions are the quantile functions for teir respective distributions.  You feed them a quantile, $q$, then return the $x$ such that $F(x)=q$.

How this is done in practice depends on what distribution you're working with.  Inverting the CDF may be a fun exercise, but not one I'm interested in doing right now.  You could use any number of root finding methods to solve

$$F(x)-q=0$$

for $x$ which should yield the correct quantile with sufficiently many iterations.

Comment: Ok so but how does it find that point? Does it loop over the alpha until a value is found that matches the desired density?

Comment: One way would be to write down the CDF and then invert it algebraically.  That isn't likely possible with the chi-square density, so the other option is to use root finding methods to solve $F(x)-q=$ for $x$.  Finally, you can actually see how `qchisq` is implemented by looking up the source code (`qchisq` calls the method for the quantile function for the gamma distirbution.  Find the code [here](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/nmath/qgamma.c))